# is it possible to build Polymer.dart elements by separate?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

Using polymer.dart I would like to convert the dart.code into javascript code. For example I know that next code:

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('click-counter')
class ClickCounter extends PolymerElement {
  @published int count = 0;

  ClickCounter.created() : super.created();

  void increment() {
    count++;
  }
}
```

should be converted in something like this:

```
Polymer('click-counter', {
  create: function() {},
  count: 0,
  increment: function() {
    this.count++;
  },
});
```

However I don't find any documentation in doing this. Is there any library/transformer for doing this or I should create a custom tramsformer for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible to use Polymer.dart elements in Polymer.js applications but I think the Dart team is working to make this possible but I have not more knowledge about the progress.